# How come Sam is alive at all?

Tags: game-of-thrones

At the very final scene of the second season of Game of Thrones, something weird happens.

> Sam notices a White Walker along with an army of wights, all heading his way. Since he can't run, he hides. But when we see the White Walker, it seems that he and Sam look at each other.
>
>
>  And for some reason, the White Walker doesn't kill Sam. And even if he didn't really see him. It was my impression that they could sense humans in their vicinity. Surely Sam would have set these internal alarms of the icy CGI warrior.

So how is Sam alive at all??

Comment: I tried to do my best to avoid spoilers. But I feel that it wasn't enough. Any further help would be appreciated!

Comment: That scene does not happen in the books, so best ask the script writers. I assume they just wanted to show off their nice CGI graphics.

Comment: @LordSnow: I think you’ve deftly avoided spoilers, at least as far as possible.

Comment: See: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11810/did-the-white-walkers-spare-sam

Comment: See also: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35987/white-walkers-sparing-the-odd-member-of-the-nights-watch

Comment: @Mooz: The suggested duplicate doesn't quite answer my question; but the off-site suggestion seems to do the trick (to some extent, I can't say I'm fully satisfied, but I doubt I'll be without talking to the writers of the episode). Thanks!

Comment: @LordSnow No; not quite duplicates, that's why I only linked them :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are walking along a forest path and you see a gnat on a tree, you don't make the effort to go over and kill it.

The whitewalker is the same. He saw Sam, evaluated the situation and saw him as basically nothing. less than a threat. So puny, pitiful and pathetic that he didn't even bother to gesture to have one of his underlings go over and slay him.

Comment: No, but if you are walking along a forest path in order to kill gnats, and you see one on a tree, you will kill it. The White Walker is the same, he was presumably heading over to kill men.

Comment: The White Walker was interested in the baby, and wasn't in a mission to kill every human he encounters, and given that Sam wasn't perceived as dangerous  he let him be.

Answer (score 1):

It may be the white walker didn't see the sam. When the white walker calling His army to attack and White walker must be far away behind the stone to see the Sam and his is looking only his army.